# Should I set nullable to false or true?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe in spark and I don't understand what the `nullable` property means, Should I set it to false or keep true :

for example:

```
root
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- invited: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- day_diff: long (nullable = true)
 |-- interested: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- event_owner: long (nullable = true)
 |-- friend_id: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Some of the fields in the dataframe could be null. Which means that data is missing.

Comment: It means, row with nullable can accept either null or not null value

Comment: Please tag spark questions with `apache-spark` so non-spark scala users can avoid them! (Thanks!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nullable indicates if the concerned column can be null or not.
It ensures that a specific column can't be null (if it's null while the nullable property is set to true, Spark will launch a java.lang.RuntimeException during the first action on the dataframe).

Here's an example here where we set the first row's value to null while the nullable property of this column is set to false :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val data = Seq(
  Row(null, "a"),
  Row(5, "z")
)

val schema = StructType(
 List(
   StructField("num", IntegerType, false),
   StructField("letter", StringType, true)
 )
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
 spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
 schema
)
df.show()
```

You'll then have the following exception, saying that the column num can't be having null values :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'num' of input row cannot be null.
```

PS : the nullable value is set to true by default, you don't have to set it, unless you want it to be false.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3d5c61e5fd24f07302e39b5d61294da79aa0c2f9/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructField.scala#L39

I hope it helps

Comment: so this property we can choose it false,for example , if this column is a  PRIMARY KEY column or we knew this column shouldn't be null, do we?

Comment: exactly, if we don't want a column (for example the PRIMARY KEY as you said) to be null, we set the nullable property to false.

Comment: is there a way we can do that using spark SQL?